# Loading multiple viewcomponents in an ASP.net core 2.2 cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm new to Asp.Net core but i have worked with Asp.net MVC 5.I have a problem with loading multiple view components inside a view.(using Asp.net core 2.2)
I have page which loads a `viewcomponent` inside it.
This is my page:

```html
    <div id="frmSoftPhone_pageUniqueId">
            <div id="sipClient" class="custom-tab">
                <ul>       

                     <li class="active"
                            data-init="init"
                            data-parentObj="cc.pageDesktop"><i class="icon-desktop"></i></li>
                </ul>
               <div id="desktop-container" class="active" style="height: 650px">
                        @await  Component.InvokeAsync("TestViewComponent")
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And then inside my '`TestViewComponent`' i am loading a few `viewcomponents` too.
my TestViewComponent is this

```html
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-item">
            <div class="custom-tab">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active session-content-li"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i></li>
                    <li style="position: relative">
                        <span id="v-call-count" style="display: none">0</span><span class="icon-queue"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="position: relative">
                        <span id="p-call-count" style="display: none">0</span><span class="icon-p-queue"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="active session-content">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("GroupEmail", new GroupEmailModel())
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CallHistory")
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("SmsContainer")
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="tabcontent">
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("OnlineAgentstatus")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="tabcontent">
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("VCallsContainer")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="tabcontent">
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("PCallsContainer")
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

None of my `viewcomponents` have 'async' code.By debugging I see that all my `viewcomponents` are loading by trace but finally when everything finishes there is just first component 'GroupEmail'.Also when changing the loading order of the `viewcomponents`, again just first one or sometimes 2 of them is loaded inside the HTML.Also I tried using `Html.PartialAsync` and Html.Partial too.but the same result happened.
I'm getting stuck on this problem for 2 days.Any help i'll appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found,

There was a mistake on kendo model wrong binding in a column.So just corrected it and all the viewcomponents are working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I found something by testing it again and again.I have Kendo grids or treelist inside the partial views(all of them).When removing them everything is fine and it works.I'm trying to find the exact issue if solve it i will post the solution here.

Thanks